# Compojure API running ring server raises map exception

Tags: clojure, swagger, leiningen, ring, compojure-api

I'm following [this](https://www.anthony-galea.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-compojure-api/) tutorial on how to use the compojure api and have run into a dead end with this exception:

```
lein ring server
2022-08-09 23:19:55.538:INFO::main: Logging initialized @921ms
WARN clojure.tools.logging not found on classpath, compojure.api logging to console.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Map literal must contain an even number of forms, compiling:(ring_test/core.clj:16:16)
```

I have kept everything the same as the tutorial except changed my routes to a test route:

```
(ns ring-test.core
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            [ring.util.http-response :refer :all]))

(def app
  (api
   {:swagger
    {:ui "/"
     :spec "swagger.json"
     :data {:info {:tile "Test"}
            :tags [{:name "api"}]}}
    (context "/api" []
      :tags ["api"]
      (GET "/test" []
        :body ["test"]
        (ok)))}))
```

and updated some of the versions in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject ring-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" 
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [metosin/compojure-api "2.0.0-alpha28"]]
  :ring {:handler ring-test.core/app}
  :profiles {:dev
             {:plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.5"]]
              :dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]]}})
```

If anyone could help me with this issue that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, (context ...) is outside the map.

```
(def app
  (api {:swagger
        {:ui   "/"
         :spec "/swagger.json"
         :data {:info {:title "Account Service"}
                :tags [{:name "api"}]}}} ;; END-OF-MAP HERE

       ;; This from is _NOT_ in the map
       (context "/api" []
                :tags ["api"]
                (POST "/account" []
                      :body [account (describe NewAccount "new account")]
                      (ok))
                (POST "/transfer" []
                      :body [transfer (describe NewTransfer "new transfer")]
                      (ok)))))
```

The problem is in your version, you move (context ...) inside this map.

```
(def app
  (api {:swagger {:ui "/"
                  :spec "swagger.json"
                  :data {:info {:tile "Test"}
                         :tags [{:name "api"}]}}

        ;; This from is in the map
        (context "/api" []
                 :tags ["api"]
                 (GET "/test" []
                      :body ["test"]
                      (ok)))
        } ;; END-OF-MAP HERE
       ))
```

You can fix this by moving (context ...) to outside the map as shown in the tutorial.